# Norm on $D(A)$ where $A$ is a unbounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E,F$ Banach spaces. Brezis calls a operator $A: D(A)\subset E\to F$, where $D(A)$ is a subspace such that $\overline{D(A)} = E$ of unbounded linear operator.

In some exercise he gives the following hint: Consider $D(A)$ with the graph norm. In this case, if $A$ is closed, then $D(A)$ with such norm is a Banach space.

So my point is, what does mean to consider $D(A)$ with the graph norm? This is weird since $D(A)\subset E$. Is he meaning that $A$ can be view as the operator $A : (u,v) \in F^{\ast}\times E\mapsto \langle u,Av\rangle$ and $\|A(u,v)\| := \|u\| + \|Av\|?,$ where $D(A)$ is thought as a subespace of $F^{\ast}\times E?$

Comment: This might help: [Closed operators](https://isem.math.kit.edu/images/6/69/AppendixA.pdf)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This helped more than you think.

Comment: $(\mathcal{D}(A),\|\cdot\|_A)$ is a normed space, where $\|x\|_A = \|x\|_E+\|Ax\|_F$. This space is a Banach space if $A$ is closed. This norm is the norm induced by $x \mapsto \langle x,Ax\rangle \in \mathcal{G}(A)\subset E\times F$.